# MySQL insert user in to a group which is owned by another user

Tags: php, mysql

I have a situation where I need to be able to assign users to multiple groups which are owned by me (current user) however not sure the best method. I have read some other posts but I think my requirement is slightly different.

The situation is for a mobile app in AS3 that allows registered users to create friends and groups then assign friends to groups.

Currently my table structure is:

```
User table
id    username
--------------
1     user1
2     user2
3     user3

Friend link table
id    user_id    friend_user_id
-------------------------------
1     1          2
2     2          1
3     1          3
4     3          1

Group table
id    group_name    user_id
---------------------------
1     group1        1
2     group2        1

Group link table
id    group_id    user_id
-------------------------
1     1           2
2     2           2
3     1           3
```

Basically a user creates an account which sets an ID, they then add friends which can be other registered users. This creates 2 records in the friend link table (one for each user). The user can then create groups (groups are linked by user ID). Then the user can assign their friends to groups.

I guess I have 3 questions:

1. Is the current structure correct for such a situation?
2. Because I need to show all the available groups when adding/removing users, how should I insert/delete the data once the user saves the friend/group link?

Thanks

EDIT: Question 2 continued - I have been able to write the selected groups to the group link table by passing an array from the app to a PHP script by setting the group ID, user ID and an isSelected flag however this fails when users are removed from groups because I am only passing the selected groups, not the unselected ones.

Comment: The structure seems reasonable. Not sure I understand question 2. Show what you've tried, and explain how it's not working; don't just ask open-ended questions.

Comment: Added additional information. Now that I write it is seems like I should be passing ALL group ID's to the PHP script from the app instead of just the selected ones.

Comment: So you're not going to show your code?

Comment: I would suggest a little bit more clarification on question 2. The problem is keeping data integrity? Do you save the friend link first and then the group link?

Comment: Correct. A user can be friends with multiple people however they both must be registered (and confirm friend status) to be able to be added to a group. A user must create a group and friend link before adding the friend to a group link. Not really sure how else to explain it. The issue is not added friends to groups but what you mentioned, keeping data integrity when friends are removed from groups OR when a friend is remove from the friend link

Comment: I think your real issue here is your DB design. I understand you have an idea with the friend link and groups and such but I think you're making you're DB too complicated and thus creating your data integrity issues when trying to do simple things like deleting links. I would suggest sitting down and hand drawing this out and try to keep it KISS (keep it simple stupid)

Comment: haha, I did and I thought I was!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A suggestion I have for you DB structure would be what is the difference between a friend list and a group list? Both are groups of people under a specific title, correct? To me it seams like you might have some unnecessary overhead due to repeated linking.

For instance, I would make a suggestion of changing the group table to more like

```
group_id: int not_null auto_increment
owner_id: int not_null
group_name: varchar(125) not_null
```

And then have a group_join table

```
group_joinid: int not_null auto_increment
groupid: int not_null
userid: int not_null
```

Where groupid is from the group table and userid is from the user table. I don't know the size of your audience so this approach might need to be tweak, but this seams to eliminate the potential of repeated linking between users and groups

Comment: This still poses the question about how to remove users from groups if I am only passing selected groups. I am passing the user ID and the friend user ID, would it be bad to remove all group link records which match the friend user ID and all group ID's owned by the user before inserting a new set of selected groups?

Comment: Then you would just use a join and delete DELETE FROM group_join as gj jOIN group as g ON gj.group_id = g.groupid WHERE g.owner_id = [userid] AND gj.userid = [friends userid]

Comment: What you mentioned above is pretty much what I have expect I also have a friend link table which acts the same as a group table. Friend link is between 2 users. Group is owned by a user and that user puts other users in the group link (join) table. Unless I am missing something

Comment: I will give your suggestion a go...thanks